# Xcode build failure

Tags: xcode

creating a build getting this error

> ld: library not found for -lPods-Swan
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[image]

Comment: Mind including a bit more information about your build?  What does your Podfile look like?

Answer (score 0):

Deleted -lPods-Swan.a in main project and now works.